# How to speed up dataframe search and assign value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, I have two dataframes

df1:

```
        0        1           2           3 
0      Name     Unit      Attribute     Date
1      a        A           xxy         xxx
2      b        B           xyx         xxx
3      c        C           xxx         xxx
4      d        D           yxx         xxx
5      e        E           yxy         yyy
```

df2:

```
        0        1        2       
      Name     Unit      Date
0      a        F        xxx
1      b        G        xxx
2      e        H        xxx
3      f        I        xxx
```

I want to overwrite the entries in df1 with their corresponding entries in df2.

For example, overwrite df1.loc[5,3] by df2.loc[2,2]. That is to say, for rows with with the same 'Name', overwrite df1's same column if it is in df2.

Currently, I am doing this in a stupid way:

```
def find_column_num(key, df_name, start_row, stop_row, start_column, stop_column):
    for i in range(start_row,stop_row+1):
        for j in range(start_column, stop_column+1):
            if df_name.loc[i,j]== key:
                column_num_with_key = j
                return column_num_with_key
                break 

for i in range(0,len(df1.index)):
    for ii in range(0,len(df2.index)):
       if df1.loc[i,0] == df2.loc[ii,0]:
          for j in range(0,len(df1.columns)):
              if df1.loc[0,j] in df2.loc[0,:]:
                   df1.set_value(i,j, df2.loc[ii,find_column_num(df1.loc[0,j],df2,0,0,0,len(df2.columns))]
```

I am not proud of it. I did a bit research and came up with replacing '=' with set_value(), which helps. I truly look forward to hear other suggestions. The size of the actual problem is 200 rows and 30 columns. So, running through all the for loops takes 20 seconds.

Comment: What is the output?

Comment: Expected output... please. You need `merge`

Comment: Next time, please don't post unclean, non-loadable inputs with all the values identical (xxx).  It makes it pointlessly difficult to test.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have changed the code and tested it in jupyter notebook.

Comment: Hi COLDSPEED, Thx for your help. I have tried your answer but it did not work. Meanwhile, I have formalized my question so that it can be run, with an expected output. Could you have a look at the question again? Maybe you will see what I try to achieve?

Comment: @COLDSPEED I did ask a new question, which is relevant but not the same. That is also why I think it would be cleaner to set the new question as a separate one. This question is about what is the fastest way to do a task. The new question is, if it is already determined to divide the task in step a and and step b, what is the fastest way to do step b.

Comment: @COLDSPEED I suppose you are not willing to answer the modified question?

Comment: @COLDSPEED Thanks. I am checking it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use `merge` and `fillna`. You'll need to clean your data a bit. Here's what I used for reference.

```
 df1

  Name Unit Attribute Date
0    a    A       xxy  xxx
1    b    B       xyx  xxx
2    d    C       xxx  xxx
3    e    D       yxx  xxx
4    e    E       yxy  xxx

df2

  Name Unit Date
0    a    F  xxx
1    b    G  xxx
2    e    H  xxx
3    f    H  xxx
```

---

```
out = df1[['Name', 'Attribute']].merge(df2, how='left').fillna(df1)
out

  Name Attribute Unit Date
0    a       xxy    F  xxx
1    b       xyx    G  xxx
2    d       xxx    C  xxx
3    e       yxx    H  xxx
4    e       yxy    H  xxx
```